# Adding WinForms in TFS and Managing it

Tags: tfs

I have created an application in WinForms and I have used nearly 10 SQL files and some other .ico files and I have kept all those files in 2 separate folders 'Support' and 'Resources'. I have written code to load files from it application startup path. Currently I have placed these 2 folders in the Bin folder
So my doubt is when I check-in this project in TFS, I don't want to add the 'Bin' and its sub folders but When somebody take its latest version from TFS and build the code then the 2 folders should come in the Bin folder. How can I achieve this.
My current folder structure is as below:
[My current folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxYIE.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can:

1. Add new folders into your project
2. Add files into the new folders.
3. Set "Copy if newer" in Copy to Output Directory for each file. Example:

[image]